# What technical considerations must a system/network administrator worry about when a site gets onto social bookmarking/sharing sites?

Tags: system-administration

The reason I ask is that Stack Overflow has been [Slashdotted](http://slashdot.org/firehose.pl?op=view&id=1170403), and [Redditted](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/71i4v/stack_overflow_launched_into_public/).

First, what kinds of effect does this have on the servers that power a website? Second, what can be done by system administrators to ensure that their sites remain up and running as best as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you haven't planned for this before it happens, it's probably too late and your users will have a poor experience.

Scalability is your first immediate concern.  You may start getting more hits per second than you were getting per month.  Your first line of defense is good programming and design.  Make sure you're not doing anything stupid like reloading data from a database multiple times per request instead of caching it.  Before the spike happens, you need to do some fairly realistic load tests to see where the bottlenecks are.

For absurdly high traffic, consider the ability to switch some dynamic pages over to static pages.

Having a server architecture that can scale also helps.  Shared hosts generally don't scale.  A single dedicated machine generally doesn't scale.  Using something like Amazon's EC2 to host can help, especially if you plan for a cluster of servers from the beginning (even if your cluster is a single computer).

You're next major concern is security.  You're suddenly a much bigger target for the bad guys.  Make sure you have a good security plan in place.  This is something you should always have, but it become more important with high usage.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly, ask if you really want to spend weeks and thousands of $ on planning  for something that might not even happen, and if it does happen, lasts about 5 hours.**

Easiest solution is to have a good way to switch to a page simply allowing a signup. People will sign up and you can email them when the storm has passed.

More elaborate solutions rely on being able to scale quickly. That's firstly a software issue (can you connect to a db on another server, can you do load balancing). Secondly, your hosting solution needs to support fast expansion. Amazon EC2 comes to mind, or maybe slicehost. With both services you can easily start new instances ("Let's move the database to a different server") and expand your instances ("Let's upgrade the db server to 4GB RAM").

If you keep all data in the db (including sessions), you can easily have multiple front-end servers. For the database I'd usually try a single server with the highest resources available, but only because I haven't worked with db replication and it used to be quite hard to do, at least with mysql. Things might have improved.

Answer (score 0):

The app designer needs to think about scaling up (larger machines with more cores and higher performance) and/or scaling out (distributing workload across multiple systems).  The IT guy needs to work out how to best support that. The network is what you look at first, because obviously everything rides on top of it. Starting at the border, that usually means network load balancers and redundant routers being served by multiple providers. You can also look at geographic caching services and apps such as cachefly.

You want to reduce your bottlenecks as much as possible. You also want to design the environment such that it can be scaled out as needed without much work. Do the design work up front and it'll mean less headaches when you do get dugg.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (of what I used in the past and current projects):
For boosting performance (if needed) you can put a reverse-proxying, caching squid in front of your server. Of course that only works if you don't have session keys and if the pages are somewhat static (means: they change only once an hour or so) and not personalised. 
With the squid you can boost a bloated and slow CMS like typo3, thus having the performance of static websites with the comfort of a CMS.

You can outsource large files to external services like Amazon S3, saving your server's bandwidth.

And if you are able to spend some (three-figures per month) bucks, you can as well use a Content Delivery Network. Whith that in place you automatically have scaling, high-availability and low latencys for your users. Of course, your pages must be cachable, so session keys and personalised pages are a no-no. If designed carefully and with CDNs in mind, you can at least cache SOME content, like pics and videos and static stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The load goes up, as other answers have mentioned.

You'll also get an influx of new users/blog comments/votes from bored folks who are only really interested in vandalism. This is mostly a problem for blogs which allow completely anonymous commenting, where some dreadful stuff will be entered. The blog platform might have spam filters sufficient to block it, but manual intervention is frequently required to clean up remaining drivel.

Even a little barrier to entry, like requiring a user name or email address even if no verification is done, will dramatically reduce the volume of the vandalism.